# Need help disassembling Groehe shower thermostat

Tags: shower, thermostat, faucet

I have what I think is a Grohe 19624 Shower thermostat like this the one shown here: http://www.guillens.com/index.jsp?path=product&part=392046.

It is leaking and I need to get it apart to replace some o-rings. But, I can't for the life of me figure out how you get the handle off. There is no visible set screw anywhere. Does anyone have any idea how to get the handle off so I can get to the innards?

This is about a 16 year old part that is now discontinued so extensive internet searches have not turned up any installation or maintenance documentation. Also, because it's discontinued, I don't want to take any risk of damaging the part in trying to disassemble it either.

The exploded diagram in the above link implies that the cap would come off the end, but no amount of persuasion indicates that the cap would come off without breaking something.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew the cap and pull off the brass collar that will reveal the plastic grey temp handle.  Then there is a green clip that is split.  Pull the green clip out and the remaining handle components will come off.  I think it’s component number 1.4 in the parts breakdown.
Visit the grohe website for that trim and it’s really obvious and easy to get it apart.
Good luck!

Comment: Thx.  But, this was 3+ years ago.  I did eventually figure it out myself that you can unscrew the end cap.  After 16 years in a shower environment, not everything that's threaded turns that easily.